# Relativity of subordinate clauses introduced by different ki-vortoj

Tags: correlatives

There was a time when I said something like

> Mi havis monadon kiel dorlotbesto, kiam mi havas 12 jarojn.

But then someone corrected me, saying that it should be **havis**, instead, and showed me a corroborating page from the PMEG (I do not have it at the moment). Should verbs in some subordinate clauses not be relative? I remember that the page mentions some ki-vortoj like "kiam", "kie", "kiel", and a couple more, but, if I remember correctly, not "ke", "kiu", or "kio". What is the rule here, for relativity of tense?

Comment: Verŝajne vi volas diri: _mi havis monadon kiel dorlotbestoN_. [Jen](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/komparoj/kiel_ol/kun_rolmontriloj.html) klarigo.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Ne, estu sen akuzativo, ĉar la komparo per _kiel_ priskribas trajton de monado. La frazo ne estas mallongigo por “Mi havis monadon, kiel mi havis dorlotbeston”, sed la signifo estas: “Mi havis monadon, kiu rolis kiel dorlotbesto”. Komparu kun ĉi tia konstruo: “Tie oni verŝas vinon kiel vinagro”. La vorto “vinagro” priskribas la kvaliton de la vino (la vino estas acida); se vi dirus “Tie oni verŝas vinon kiel vinagron”, tiam la signifo estus “Tie oni verŝas vinon en la sama maniero kiel oni verŝas vinagron”. Tio tute ne estas la celata signifo.

Comment: @Joffysloffy  Tio estas Interesa... Eĉ se, laŭ mi, ankaŭ malĝusta. Mi pensis ke tio meritis apartan demandon, kaj mi [ĝin faris](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/rolmontrilo-akuzativo-post-kiel).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing this with the rule of tenses for direct and indirect speech. Normally, with a subordinate clause, the tense should just be as it would be in a normal sentence: In your example *kiam* refers to a time in the past, so the predicate (*havis*) should be in the past tense.

The thing with direct and indirect speech is that in Esperanto the tense of indirect speech should be the same as in direct speech, whereas in English this is not the case:

> I said: “I **want** a turtle”.
>   I said, that I **wanted** a turtle.

But in Esperanto:

> Mi diris: “Mi **volas** havi testudon”.
>   Mi diris, ke mi **volas** havi testudon.

---

By the way, *monado* is not an animal, but some kind of philosophical term.

Comment: Oh, sorry. In context, "monad" has become a sort of in-joke amongst us mathematical Esperantists, for being such a supposedly malfacile komprenebla "creature" in mathematics.

Comment: Haha, okay, I see! I never did that much with category theory that I had to deal with monads (fortunately, I take it haha) :p.

Comment: But, back on topic, what about "kiu" and "kio"? I remember that somebody agreed with a construction like "La monado kunpuŝiĝis kun alia monado, kio ĝin iĝas pensi pri vivo", where the "iĝi" is present relative to the "kunpuŝiĝi". Should the "iĝi" have been in past tense, too, as it does not seem to be a case of indirect speech?

Comment: That was me haha. It was this sentence: “La aĵo kunpuŝiĝis kun la alia aĵo, kio igas ĝin pensi pri vivo.” To be honest, I did not pay attention to the tenses, but this just shows a difference in time between the two situations: the _kunpuŝiĝo_ is in the past from the perspective of the reader, whilst the _igas_ is in the present. That is actually weird, and should just be _igis_. Normally you just express the order of events by words as _antaŭ ol_ or _post kiam_, or _dum_, etc. but I don't remember ever explicitly writing the tense of a subordinate clause relative to that of the main clause.

Comment: I cannot actually find this in PMEG. And in another Dutch highly esteemed reference book I cannot find it either. So I reckon it is not really a thing and you just use simple tenses relative to the current situation from where you are describing it. It only happens when you use -_e_-participles: _Mi havis mondadon, **havante** 12 jarojn_; if you used _havinte_, then you would have a monad _after_ you were 12 years old, not during.

Comment: Then I suppose that the rule is that relativity only applies in cases of indirect speech (e.g. "li diris, ke ...", "ĝi montris, ke ...").

Comment: Exactly, it is only ever an issue with indirect speech (and -_e_-participles).

Comment: Yes, for verbs in any _modo_ you use the same tense for direct and indirect speech. That's one of the reasons, why _us-_ and _u-modoj_ are timeless. The time in participles is always relative to the main verb of a sentence: happens before (_-i(n)t-_), same time (_-a(n)t-_) or after (_-o(n)t-_). Adverbal forms of participles often corresponds to _frazekvivalentoj_ in other languages. They can be tricky to get right and especially in passive can be really hard to understand, so I would avoid saying "Mi havis mondadon havante 12 jarojn" and would prefer a subordinate clause here.

Answer (score 2):

That someone was right. [This](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/aliaj_ki-vortoj.html) explains how it works and you will notice that the tenses are the same, on both sides of *kiam*.

Another way to see it, in sentences like yours you should also be able to turn the two parts around:

```
kiam mi estis en la urbo, mi aĉetis novan robon. 

mi aĉetis novan robon kiam mi estis en la urbo.
```

but you cannot do that for:

```
Mi havis monadon kiel dorlotbesto, kiam mi havas 12 jarojn.

Kiam mi havas 12 jarojn. Mi havis monadon kiel dorlotbesto.
```

Or you can think about the ommited *tiam* in the sentence, and the need for the pair *kiam*/*tiam* to share the same tense:

```
kiam mi estis en la urbo, (tiam) mi aĉetis novan robon.
```