# Rolmontrilo/akuzativo post kiel por rolo/funkcio

Tags: accusative

En [ĵusa demando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/relativity-of-subordinate-clauses-introduced-by-different-ki-vortoj) oni skribis ion ĉi tian:

```
Mi havis araneon kiel dorlotbesto.
```

Mi opinias ke tio signifus:

```
Mi havis araneon tiel, kiel
dorlotbesto havus araneon.
```

Sed, se oni aldonas *-n* al *dorlotbesto*:

```
Mi havis araneon kiel dorlotbeston.
```

Tio signifus:

```
Mi havis araneon tiel, kiel
oni havas dorlotbeston.
```

Tion, laŭ mia kompreno, detale pravigas PMEG [ĉi tie](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/komparoj/kiel_ol/kiel_rolo_funkcio.html).

Notu ke laŭ PMEG eĉ se oni povas konstrui klarigajn frazojn en kiuj la koncernata vorto ne havas -n, oni devas uzi -n se ĝi aperas en klariga frazo kiu esprimas *manieron*.

Ekzemple, la *-n* oni bezonas en la jena frazo:

```
Vi povus ricevi lin kiel edzon.FA1.4
   ... por ke li estu via edzo.
   ... tiel, kiel oni ricevas edzon.
```

Kaj, mi pensas, en la frazo de mia demando:

```
Vi havis araneon kiel dorlotbeston
   ... por roli kiel dortolbesto.
   ... tiel, kiel oni havas dorlotbeston
```

Tamen, en komento de tiu demando iu detale klarigas kial la -n *devas* fakte foresti.

*estu sen akuzativo, ĉar la komparo per kiel priskribas trajton de monado. La frazo ne estas mallongigo por “Mi havis monadon, kiel mi havis dorlotbeston”, sed la signifo estas: “Mi havis monadon, kiu rolis kiel dorlotbesto”....* (vi povas legi la ceteron [ĉi tie](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/relativity-of-subordinate-clauses-introduced-by-different-ki-vortoj)).

Mi pensas ke estas intersa afero, kiu meritas sian propran demandon.

Ĉu gramatike la -n ĉiam bezonatas en la kondiĉoj de PMEG (*kiel* por priskribi rolon/funkcion) aŭ ĉu ne?

Answer (score 1):

(Mi komprenas la argumenton por ellasi la akuzativo en kompara kazo.)

Tamen oni povus klare diri:

> Tie oni verŝas [tian] vinon kia vinagro.

Mi preferus solidan regulon de kazo kongrua al objekto respektive subjekto de la ĉefa frazo. Tro da gramatika, lingvisma teoriumado ne helpas al nia lingvo.

Ekzistas tamen:

> Mi opinias tion bela.

Tio tre rilatas al la uzo de *kiel* en komparo.

> Tie oni verŝas vinon kvazaŭ vinagro.

Tio jam justigas la neakuzativan uzon de *kiel* / *samkiel*.

Mi opinias *kiel* evitinda en tiu kazo.

Comment: Mi ne klare vidas en via respondo respondon al la demando. Ĉu mi komprenas bone, ke vi opinias _kiel_ evitinda en la origina frazo, tamen se oni ja uzus _kiel_, tiam estu sen akuzativo? (Do “Mi havis araneon kiel dorlotbesto” kaj ne “… kiel dorlotbeston”?)

Comment: @Joffysloffy (Evitinda pro la neklara signifo. Same _kvazaŭ_ ne vere esprimas la staton. Eble _samkiel_.) Post "Ekzistas tamen" mi vidas argumento favore al la neakuzativa uzo. Tamen samtempe la tuta afero ne faras Esperanton nia simpla lingvo. Idistoj ridu.

Answer (score 0):

Estis mi, kiu faris tiun komenton, do mi ankaŭ respondos ĉi tie. En la referencita komento mi montris ekzemplon por la argumento ne uzi akuzativon:

> Tie oni verŝas vinon kiel vinagro.

Estas du manieroj interpreti tiun frazon.
(1) Ordinare kun kompara *kiel*, se la vorto post *kiel* ne havas akuzativon, oni supozas, ke ĝi funkcias kiel la subjekto. En tiu interpreto oni devas subkompreni alian kopion de *verŝas* post *kiel*:

> Tie oni verŝas vinon kiel vinagro [verŝas vinon].

(2) Sed estas ankaŭ alia interpreto, kiu estas la celata signifo: la komparo ne temas pri la maniero, laŭ kiu oni verŝas, sed la komparo celas la *kvaliton* aŭ *trajton* de la vino: la vino, kiun oni tie verŝas, estas acida kiel vinagro:

> Tie oni verŝas vinon [tian] kiel vinagro.

(3) Se oni metas akuzativon post *vinagro*, tiam la signifo tute ŝanĝiĝas:

> Tie oni verŝas vinon kiel vinagron.

Nun la signifo, simile al (1), estas

> Tie oni verŝas vinon kiel [oni verŝas] vinagron.

T.e., tie oni verŝas vinon en la sama maniero, kiel oni verŝas vinagron (malsamaj teĥniko, ofteco, kvanto, ktp). Tio ne estas la celata signifo.

---

Normale oni decidas, ĉu uzi aŭ ne uzi akuzativon post la vorto post *kiel* depende de tio, ĉu oni volas (1) aŭ (3). Sed sen akuzativo estas ankaŭ la senco de (2), kio povas esti konfuza. PMEG ja subtenas tion en la jenaj ekzemploj:

> *Li vizitis tiajn urbojn, kiaj estas Parizo kaj Londono.* → **Li vizitis (tiajn) urbojn kiaj Parizo kaj Londono.** Prefere diru: ***Li vizitis (tiajn) urbojn kiel Parizo kaj Londono***.

[Fonto](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/komparoj/kiel_ol/chu_mallongigitaj_frazoj.html) (emfazo mia). Rimarku, ke ne skribiĝas *Parizo**n** kaj Londono**n***. Ĉi tie la frazparto *Parizo kaj Londono* estas uzata por priskribi la trajtojn de la urboj, kiujn *li* vizitis. Ne: Li vizitis la urbojn, samkiel li vizitis Parizo**n** kaj Londono**n**; nek: Li vizitis la urbojn, samkiel Parizo kaj Londono vizitis la urbojn.

En [ĉi tiu paĝo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/komparoj/kiel_ol/kun_rolmontriloj.html) estas pli da ekzemploj. Specife ĉi tiu kun klarigo:

> *Skulptu al vi du ŝtonajn tabelojn* [tiajn] ***kiel la unuaj*** [tabeloj].<sup>[Er.34](https://tekstaro.com/pl/prenitutantekston.pl?nomo=malnova-testamento&id=ar429&serchesprimo=[Ss]kulptu%20al%20vi%20du%20%C5%9Dtonajn%20tabelojn%20kiel%20la%20unuaj.?&sekcio=mtlibro2#ar429)</sup> = *...du ŝtonajn tabelojn tiajn, kiaj estis la unuaj tabeloj.* Se oni diras *kiel la unuajn*, la senco fariĝas alia: *...tiamaniere, kiel vi skulptis la unuajn tabelojn*.

Rimarku, ke la origina frazo estas “Skulptu al vi du ŝtonajn tabelojn kiel la unuaj”.

Simile:

> Mi faros vian ĉielon kiel fero kaj vian teron kiel kupro.

[Fonto](https://tekstaro.com/pl/prenitutantekston.pl?nomo=malnova-testamento&id=ar570&serchesprimo=[Mm]i%20faros%20vian%20%C4%89ielon%20kiel%20fero%20kaj%20vian%20teron%20kiel%20kupro.?&sekcio=mtlibro3#ar570).

Comment: Ni ne miksu la komparan _kiel_ kun tiu kiu priskribas rolon/funkcion. Ili kondutas malsame. Mi ŝanĝis la titolon de la demando por klarigi tion, kvankam mia demando tion jam montris: _Ĉu gramatike la -n ĉiam bezonatas en la kondiĉoj de PMEG (kiel por priskribi rolon/funkcion) aŭ ĉu ne?_

Answer (score 0):

Uzo de la vorto "kiel" por priskribi rolon estas unu el la malfacilaj aferoj en Esperanto, ĉar mankas sufiĉe klara montrilo por tio, kion oni ofte montras per [esivo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esivo) kaj [translativo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translativo) en la finno-ugraj lingvoj.

Ekz.

> Kiel prezidento Niinistö rajtis nonumi brigadan generalon Pasi Jokinen kiel novan komandanton de la aerarmeo.

La unua kiel montras esivon: Niinistö jam estas prezidento. Kp. kun la germana ***als** der Präsident*.

La dua kiel montras translativon: Jokinen fariĝas komandanto. Kp. kun la germana ***zum** Kommandeur*.

Problemo ekestas, kiam tia esiva esprimo estas parto de rekta objekto.

> Mi havis araneon kiel dorlotbeston : fi (*lemmikkieläin*→) *lemmikkieläime**nä***, de ***als** das Haustier*

Do kaj "kiel + nominativo" kaj "kiel + akuzativo" povas montri la esivon.

Plie notu, ke ne eĉ ekzistas unusenca montrilo por la translativo. Vi jam vidis antaŭe, ke "kiel + akuzativo" povas montri translativan sencon. Aliaj translativaj esprimoj estas

- Mi farbis la muron blanka : la muro iĝas blanka
- Ri varmigis la metalon ĝis fandiĝo : la metalo iĝas fandiĝita

Eble estas pliaj.

Sume nur la ĉefverbo kaj la kunteksto malkovras tiun, kiun "kiel" montras.