# "What thing?" vs "Which thing?"

Tags: correlatives

> A: "You have such a cute monad!"
>   B: "What monad?"

One's first instinct may be to translate the latter phrase as "Kiu monado?". However, how would one distinguish between the following two meanings thereof?

> "What monad?" (I have a pet monad?)
>   "Which monad?" (out of my many monads)

My guess is that it is still "kiu", as "Kio monado?" sounds kind of off, but then how would one disambiguate between the two nuances? Context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
"You have such a cute dog!"
Vi havas beletan hundon!
```

If you are suprised, say because you only have cats, then you could say:

```
What dog?
Ĉu hundon?
```

(it is a bit what you looked for when you mentioned *kio hundo?*)

Maybe you have many dogs and you'd like to know which one is the cute one, then:

```
Which dog?
Kiun hundon?
```

You will be understood if you ask:

```
Kiu hundo?
```

But it doesn't feel right, not to mirror the `-n` ending in the question if you don't make it a full sentence.

For example, this could be a dialog:

```
- Vi havas ion moviĝantan sur la kapo!!
- Kion?
```

or

```
- Atentu! Vi havas beston ĉedorse!
- Neee, kiun beston?
```

If the question does not use `-n` then you would answer without it (if you are not rephrasing it):

```
- Estas io inter viaj dentoj...
- Kio? Ĉu laktuko?
```

See this part of a play by Zamenhof (La rabistoj):

```
Maljuna Moor. –
   Kompaton! ... en la nuna minuto
   oni juĝas mian infanon!

Rabisto Moor, ektimigite. –
   Kiun infanon?
```

Comment: I think your "Kio? Ĉu <io>?" example makes the most sense to me. However, I am still curious about that "Kia <io>?" in the other answer. If that is also valid, how often is that one used?

Comment: I don't think it is valid. The answer to _kia(n)_ is an adjective. The other person just said "beleta" so asking for an adjective again, doesn't make a lot of sense, you could get "beleta" again. _Vi havas verdan jakon! / Kian? / Verdan._ In this dialog you would do that (ask _kia(n)_) only if you didn't understand the adjective because there was a sudden noise for example.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine a following conversation

> - Mi havas monadon kiel dotlotbeston.
>
> - Kio? Kio estas monado?

Comment: In my case, however, both speakers do know what a monad is, but if B does not own a monad, what would B say? I still think it is something like "Kiu monado?", but then immediately say "Ĉu mi havas monadon?", for context.

Comment: Bonvolu, monado jam signifas [ion](http://vortaro.net/#monado) kaj aliaj povus emi analizi ĝin surbaze de _mon-_. Viaj demandoj bonas, sed tiu vortelekto povus igi ilin nebezonate malpli profiteblaj por aliaj. Ĉu eblus uzi alian radikon?

Comment: Bonvolu, _mi havas monadon kiel dorlotbesto-N_. Jen [klarigoj](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/rolmontrilo-akuzativo-post-kiel-por-rolo-funkcio).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, mi legis kaj legis Pomegon kaj ŝajnas, ke vi pravas. "Kiel" estas unu el la plej superŝarĝitaj vortoj en la espa, kaj ĉi tial de tempo al tempo al mi malfacile kompreni. Mi esperas, ke estus iu klara rolmontrilo ekz. por [translativo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translativo). Tiu povus esti "ĝis", kiuj jam havas similan signifon kun tempo.

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas mi neniam estis aŭdinta pri tiu kazo. Vi povus komenci novan demandon pri tio, kiel uzi _translativon_ en la esperanta. Aspektas interese!

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, ĉu vi havas ideon, kiel mi skribos pri la temo? Kiel formuli ĝin kiel demando?

Comment: Nu, eble klarigi unue kiel oni tion uzas en via lingvo, kaj poste montri aspekton de tiu kazo, kiun vi malfacile povas esprimi en la esperanta. Aŭ, vi povus pluredakti la vikipedian artikolon, ĉar tion profitos ĉiuj. Mi legis la nunan artikolon kaj mi komprenas ke temas pri ia _-iĝ-_ elemento, sed verŝajne la afero estas pli malsimpla ol tio.

Answer (score 1):

> What monad? (I have a pet monad?)
>
> What kind of monad? (I have a pet monad?)
>
> *Kia monado?*

And

> Which monad? (out of my many monads)
>
> *Kiu monado?*

Comment: If the other person said "you have a cute _whatever_!", then I don't see how you could ever answer with "what kind of _whatever_"?

Comment: @EduardoTrápani Maybe **kiuspeca** or **kia** does not sufficiently debate the object; I am not entirely convinced it does not. _Prio kio vi parolas?_ would be an answer. **Ĉu** seems usable too.